# To read CSV file data one by one from SQL Stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need to read CSV file information one by one. i.e. If the customer in the file is existing in Customer table insert into detail table otherwise insert into error table. So I can't use bulk insert method.

How to read one by one record from CSV file? How to give the path?
Bulk insert method is not going to work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger to selectively put the row in the correct table, and then use your normal `BULK INSERT` with the option `FIRE_TRIGGERS`.

Something close to;

```
CREATE TRIGGER bop ON MyTable INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable
    SELECT inserted.id,inserted.name,inserted.otherfield FROM inserted
    WHERE inserted.id IN (SELECT id FROM customerTable);

    INSERT INTO ErrorTable
    SELECT inserted.id,inserted.name,inserted.otherfield FROM inserted
    WHERE inserted.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM customerTable);
END;

BULK INSERT MyTable FROM 'c:\temp\test.sql' 
    WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR=',', FIRE_TRIGGERS);

DROP TRIGGER bop;
```

If you're importing files regularly, you can create a table (ImportTable) with the same schema, set the trigger on that and do the imports to `MyTable` through bulk import to `ImportTable`. That way you can keep the trigger and as long as you're importing to `ImportTable`, you don't need to do any special setup/procedure for each import.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE TABLE #ImportData
(
    CVECount varchar(MAX), 
    ContentVulnCVE varchar(MAX),
    ContentVulnCheckName varchar(MAX)
)

BULK INSERT #ImportData
FROM 'D:\test.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
select * from #ImportData
//Here you can write your script to user read data one by one
DROP TABLE #ImportData
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bulk insert to load into a staging table and then process it line by line.

Comment: The staging table is a good idea, but why process it line by line? Depending on the details, using `MERGE` or just `INSERT` and `UPDATE` on the whole data set at once would be preferable.